# FB API Cookie Header Error

Tags: php, cookies, http-headers, facebook-php-sdk

I have the following code:

```
require '../lib/facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => '143944345745133',
'secret' => 'xxxxxxxx',
'cookie' => true,
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
   try {
      $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
   } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
      $user = 0;
   }
} 
if ($user) { 
  setcookie('loggedUserId', $user, time()+36000);
  setcookie('loggedUserName', $user_profile['name'], time()+36000);
} else {
  setcookie('loggedUserId', '', time()-3600);
  setcookie('loggedUserName', '', time()-3600);
}
```

and I get the error in my php error log file:

```
[17-Dec-2012 06:11:34 UTC] There exists a cookie that we wanted to clear that we 
couldn't clear because headers was already sent. Make sure to do the 
first API call before outputing anything.
```

Please help me fix it. The result user experience is that after I log in, the page needs to be reloaded to actually log in.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something in your code is outputting something before the call to setcookie. It could be a debug message. Or even an empty line before opening <?php tag.

Comment: no extra line. even tried dos2unix to make sure that there is no extra space/line

Comment: Then remove lines in a binary search fashion to find out offending line that introduces this bug. Start with just setcookie('loggedUserName', '', time()-3600); and see if it works on it own.